# Add custom value and column in SQL Table using Peewee - moves

Tags: python, mysql, database, database-migration, peewee

I am trying to write a migration script to add a new column to my existing MYSQL table.
I am using **PeeWee-moves** Library for doing, able to to basic operation but unable to add custom value in new column.

Eg :- I want to add `user_game_id` column to existing `user_info` table with "not null" constraint and by default I want some random `uuid` to be inserted to existing rows for this new column.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about peewee-moves but just run the following:

```
ALTER TABLE user_info ADD COLUMN
  user_game_id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid();
ALTER TABLE user_info ALTER user_game_id DROP DEFAULT;
```

But you have no referential integrity with the above so you can't add a proper foreign key.

I'd suggest making it nullable would be correct, especially if it's intended to act as a foreign-key.